# How can I create a URL based on controller and action method in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 3.0

I have a guestbook.jsp page where I want to create a link that points to GuestBookController's login method.

This is a simple task that most web frameworks handle this (e.g grails does it with g:link tag) but I couldn't find any documentation on this in the official SpringMVC docs.

So I am scratching my head - Is this functionality in some tag library? Does the framework expose it? Do I have to extend the framework to get this to work?

Note, I am not taking about hardcoding the url (which is an obvious but weak solution) but rather generating it based on controller and action name.

**UPDATE**:
Spring MVC doesn't provide this functionality. There is a JIRA ticket though. You can vote here https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5779

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't do this with Spring MVC currently.

It's a shame because you can do this in other frameworks including Grails (which uses Spring MVC under the hood).

See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082759/can-i-find-the-url-for-a-spring-mvc-controller-in-the-view-layer) which includes a link to a Spring feature request to add this (vote for it!)

Comment: @hemu [there's an answer with example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73970710/476716)

Answer (score 3):

Spring MVC uses the standard JSTL tags in JSPs so:

```
<c:url value="/guestBook.html" var="guestBookLink" />
<a href="${guestBookLink}">Guest Book</a>
```

In your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/guestBook")
public String handleGuestBook() { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [**Spring HATEOS library**](https://spring.io/projects/spring-hateoas) provides an API to generate links to MVC controller methods in various ways.

For example:

```java
URI url = linkTo(methodOn(GuestBookController.class).login()).toUri();
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your login method with @RequestMapping, like so:

```
@Controller
public class GuestBookController {
  ...
  @RequestMapping(value="/mycontextroot/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String login() {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, in your JSP, create a link something like this:

```
<c:url var="loginlink" value="/mycontextroot/login.html">
</c:url>
<a href="${loginlink}">Login</a>
```

This assumes that your dispatcher servlet is looking for *.html URLs.