# A utility to construct correct Url from the controller and action name?

Tags: spring-mvc

Do we have something like @url.action and @url.content in Spring MVC like ASP.net MVC? If not, I will need to create the urls to the actions myself, which is kind of messy. I feel that something like @url.action and @url.content is very nice to have.

Thanks ...

The correct question to ask should be:

Do we have a utility to contruct the correct Url by giving the controller and action name?

Sorry for the confusion, this question has been asked before. Finally found it.

[How can I create a URL based on controller and action method in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022980/how-can-i-create-a-url-based-on-controller-and-action-method-in-spring-mvc)

The answer is - no, Spring MVC does not have this support! Please go to the link to vote to add this, since majority of the MVC frameworks do have this function.

Comment: It'd be easier if you described what they did/what you're looking for.

Comment: That doesn't help; what specifically do you want to do? Construct the URL where? With what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer - Please view another post.

[How can I create a URL based on controller and action method in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022980/how-can-i-create-a-url-based-on-controller-and-action-method-in-spring-mvc)

Also .. please vote to add this feature.