# Taglib import in a JSP, how?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http: java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

this doesn't work.

What is the new taglib import statement, and how can I find a reference of others to use, and what tags there are to use.

Thanks!

Comment: Put your mouse above the `[jstl]` tag below the question and click the *info* link in the popbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's a good one to start, just put it at top of jsp :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Allows you to use [these tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html).

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. Now I need to figure out how to create a link to a @Controller/action and with params ... c:url doesnt seem to do the trick :(

Comment: c:url does do the trick ... the docs are normally a good starting point http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody

Comment: Ok, that link did not provide me with any info about c:url. I find that the doc is a bit messy and missing of detailed info. Here is a Jira about the topic, I do not belive it is possible: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5779

And stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022980/how-can-i-create-a-url-based-on-controller-and-action-method-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1):

What doesn't work?
In jsp/servlet container, there are four built-in standard tag libraries:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html

Comment: you still have to add them to your jsp's

Comment: OP didn't pay attention to markdown formatting rules. I made the missing code line to reappear again.

Comment: @NimChimpsky, right, you do have to add them to your jsps using the taglib directive as in your answer.

Comment: Not sure what you guys are discussing or recommending :S

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html try using <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> as @NimChimpsky suggested. I think the one you are using is old or incorrect.